# Distance matrix to reshaped vector of distances sorted by positions

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have a data frame of 5 items, as follows:

```
df = structure(list(item1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4), item2 = c(0, 
2, 3, 4, 0, 3, 4, 0, 4, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In addition, I have the distance matrix between the items:

```
Dist1 = structure(c(0, 1.0919530596119, 1.09195161858136, 1.0919463791331, 
1.09194754111203, 1.0919530596119, 0, 1.7831197560388, 1.78314749640301, 
1.78315668532962, 1.09195161858136, 1.7831197560388, 0, 1.78315765983813, 
1.78314839437957, 1.0919463791331, 1.78314749640301, 1.78315765983813, 
0, 1.78314787222978, 1.09194754111203, 1.78315668532962, 1.78314839437957, 
1.78314787222978, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

I would like to add a third coulmn to `df`, that will contain the distances which will somehow be extracted from `Dist1`. They have to be in the same order specified by the indices in `df`, not contain the self dist, etc.

Now, this is almost the lower triangle of `Dist1`, but not quite. (Note also that the items in `Dist1` are 1+ the item identities of `df`).

So, the expected output is:

```
df$Distances = c(1.091953, 1.783120, 1.783147, 1.783157, 1.091952, 1.783158, 
1.783148, 1.091946, 1.783148, 1.091948)
```

How can I efficiently extract this (the actual data structures are much bigger)?

Comment: How the first value is `Dist1[2, 1]` or second is `Dist1[3, 2]` ?

Comment: @RonakShah the order of the values of df is simply given from outside. The aim is to match the order of the distance matrix output to the order of df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```r
# Logic
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(item1, item2) %>% 
  mutate(Distance = Dist1[(item1)*5 + (item2 + 1)])

# Result
df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   item1, item2 [10]
   item1 item2 Distance
   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1     0     1.09
 2     1     2     1.78
 3     1     3     1.78
 4     1     4     1.78
 5     2     0     1.09
 6     2     3     1.78
 7     2     4     1.78
 8     3     0     1.09
 9     3     4     1.78
10     4     0     1.09

df$Distance
 [1] 1.091953 1.783120 1.783147 1.783157 1.091952 1.783158 1.783148 1.091946
 [9] 1.783148 1.091948
```

Comment: still not exactly clear about the logic but you get the same output directly by  `Dist1[(df$item1)*5 + (df$item2 + 1)]`.

Comment: Yes the logic is the same, [@Omry Atia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8453123/omry-atia) had mentioned `lower triangle`, so I grouped it to make sure that there are no duplicates.